# How to put space between figure in image?

Tags: html, css

How can I add some horizontal "padding space" without editing my css file? I have the code below:

```
<img src="./img/fig.jpg" align="right" style="display:inline;margin:2px;"/>
<div style="text-align:justify;">
Bunch of text.
</div>
```

I've tried specifying `style="padding-right: 5px"` for the text `div` or enclosing the `img` with  a `div` that includes padding, margins, etc. but to no avail - I can see that I can successfully add padding to above and below the text or image with this style specification, but never a space to separate the image and text..

Comment: you cannot set margin/padding on inline elements

Comment: Yes you can. Check first before you post.

Comment: @crippledlambda I cannot reproduce your problem. Putting a padding-left on the floated image does create space between the text and it. Or did you mean something else? Oh, and `align="right"` is deprecated and should be replaced with a style of `"float:right"`. Also, `display:inline` is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this and the extra suggestions... however, the solutions below worked for me. The display:inline was suggested by the org-mode help manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I get it correctly you have an image and a text to the left of it. You want to separate the text and the image with further space. What I suggest is to place an additional margin between them. Do like that:

```
<img src="./img/fig.jpg" align="right" style="display:inline;margin:2px 2px 2px 5px;"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

add float:left to the image with the padding property.

Comment: The image is already floated to the right. Floating it to the left results in a different layout.